# Ubuntu 19.04 can't connect to 5ghz wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have a wifi modem that has 2 networks, a 2.4ghz, and a 5ghz. The 2.4ghz one works fine.

Looking at the `dmesg` log, I can see that it authenticating and associating as it does on the 2.4ghz, but after associating, it deauth by local choice, and then try to connect again.

```
[   56.827430] wlp5s0: authenticate with <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]>
[   56.828007] wlp5s0: send auth to <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   56.829495] wlp5s0: authenticated
[   56.833562] wlp5s0: associate with <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   56.847597] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]> (capab=0x931 status=0 aid=1)
[   56.854726] wlp5s0: associated
[  102.033825] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  104.816857] wlp5s0: authenticate with <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]>
[  104.817522] wlp5s0: send auth to <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  104.819276] wlp5s0: authenticated
[  104.821607] wlp5s0: associate with <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  104.835516] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'VM2519618 5GHz' [AC1]> (capab=0x931 status=0 aid=1)
[  104.842661] wlp5s0: associated
```

Complete log generated by the wireless-info script:

[wireless-info.txt](https://pastebin.com/bX6c6ZXZ)

Comment: Have you tried prioritising 5GHz band?

Comment: The 2.4 and 5ghz networks have different SSIDs. It happens even when the 2.4ghz is not configured.